# Exporting with phpMyAdmin changes timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

When exporting a file through phpMyAdmin some timestamps are put back an hour. How may I prevent this? I do not want timestamps tampered with. Here's a [screenshot](http://kegoi.com/hQyze.jpg) for the curious (see the dates.)

I believe the cause may be the `SET time_zone = "+00:00";` that is added to every export file.

Is this suppose to happen? Is it a known bug?

I'm running:

```
-- Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
-- PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
```

Answer (score 1):

The times are not actually being 'tampered with'.

MySQL interally stores `TIMESTAMP` columns [converted to UTC time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), then uses a mixture of system and session (client session) values to determine what to display to the user.

You can check both of these values running the following query yourself.

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

So when your PHPMA script generates its dump, its specifying a session `time_zone` variable so when you run it MySQL will convert them all from that timezone back to UTC. When you then go to import that to another database, it will still convert them back to the UTC values you're expecting.

**So to summarise** if the values in the dump with `SET time_zone = "+00:00";` are all "1 hour behind" the values you see when querying via PHPMyAdmin, this **only appears this way** because the connection via PHPMyAdmin will have it's timezone one hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: Think I understand. So to prevent this, I should sync my development and production servers with the same time_zone = "+00:00"?

Comment: The time zone the servers are in doesn't matter. The important thing is when you export data to a file, you retain the timezone details so when you import it mysql knows which timezone that data is in. Syncing them will help reduce any potential mistakes on your behalf though.